# checking if the number is negative or not

Tags: smartpy

I have a requirement where I need to pass a byte into a function and that function should convert that byte to integer and returns true if it is negative else false.
the function will be this in the new syntax of smartpy.

```
        @sp.entrypoint
        def check_negative(self, x):
            self.data.is_negative = sp.to_int(x) < 0
```

But As I am using old syntax for writing a contract, How can I perform this computation .

I also tried deploying a contract with new syntax and writing above function on onchain_view and then calling that view from the contract with old syntax.
It didn't work too.

Can anyone help me here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is available in the alpha of SmartPy 18.1. Here is [an example](https://preview.smartpy.io/0.18.1-alpha01/ide?code=eJyVkM9KxDAQxu99iqGnBCX0JCguCIV9Au9hTKcabJOQzC7t25u0dbEiuDu3me@b3_yxY_CRIY0YOcyACVKoqpcU1Oi700BVRz2MaJ2QTxXkMAOmBK3IjtY7jmh4U0oUt9bWWdZaJBr6H1qJUlIdMiqbtKN3ZHsmOMARh0TVxVrmU4bPwVvHO7r5IPN5aV1m3MN05ZiMZZ_XYzFJeIZmvRS7TjMlFg7H4qpLUsvl9KW@0ZMhh9H6DZQV_V0S5UVyfVCWS6ZaIfdtdwcwq0X9viKotzkDRd1MzWMt943qTNH2szB_nLS9Tv7P7R9u477G0zXYprkVvC38BTp3xD0-):

```
import smartpy as sp

@sp.module
def main():
    class C(sp.Contract):
        def __init__(self):
            self.data.is_negative = False

        @sp.entrypoint
        def check_negative(self, x):
            self.data.is_negative = sp.to_int(x) < 0

@sp.add_test(name = "test")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario(main)
    c = main.C()
    scenario += c
    c.check_negative(sp.bytes("0x09"))
    scenario.verify(c.data.is_negative == False)
    c.check_negative(sp.bytes("0xf6"))
    scenario.verify(c.data.is_negative == True)
    c.check_negative(sp.bytes("0x00f6"))
    scenario.verify(c.data.is_negative == False)
```

Here is a workaround for the legacy syntax (notice that it doesn't work in the test scenario but you can originate the contract, you may use meta-programmation to mock it in scenario if you need):

```
to_int = sp.unpack(sp.constant(
            "expru2UfuHkkPH6UHCZyYuLU6BdmNhuksJkTbtAB1C1vVXiFQ9R1Ed",
            t = sp.TBytes), sp.TLambda(sp.TBytes, sp.TInt)).open_some()
```

Example:

```
import smartpy as sp

class Test(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self, in_scenario):
        self.init(is_negative=False)
        self.in_scenario = in_scenario

    @sp.entrypoint
    def check_negative(self, x):
        to_int = sp.unpack(sp.constant(
            "expru2UfuHkkPH6UHCZyYuLU6BdmNhuksJkTbtAB1C1vVXiFQ9R1Ed",
            t = sp.TBytes), sp.TLambda(sp.TBytes, sp.TInt)).open_some()
        self.data.is_negative = to_int(x) < 0

if "templates" not in __name__:
    @sp.add_test(name = "Test")
    def test():
        c1 = Test(True)
        scenario = sp.test_scenario()
        scenario += c1
```

Answer (score 1):

Direct conversion from `bytes` to `int` has been added to michelson in the latest protocol upgrade (mumbai). [Release notes](https://tezos.gitlab.io/protocols/016_mumbai.html#michelson-opcodes-for-logical-operations-on-bytes)

Unfortunately, I do not think SmartPy supports these instructions yet. In the meanwhile you can adapt the [`Nat.of_bytes`](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Acurast/acurast-hyperdrive/main/contracts/tezos/libs/utils.py) function to support decoding to int, you need to handle [2's complement](https://ryanstutorials.net/binary-tutorial/binary-negative-numbers.php).

Also, do you really need this? Is a really odd thing to do inside a smart-contract.

Answer (score 1):

You can pass the bytes that are formed using `sp.pack`. And, parse the argument using `sp.unpack`. [Here](https://legacy.smartpy.io/docs/advanced/pack_and_unpack#unpacking-data) is the legacy documentation for that.

For example, it will look something like this in the legacy syntax:

```
import smartpy as sp

class Test(sp.Contract):
    def __init__(self):
        self.init(is_negative = False)

    @sp.entry_point
    def check_negative(self, num_bytes):
        num = sp.unpack(num_bytes, sp.TInt).open_some('unpack failed to parse integer')
        is_negative = num < 0
        self.data.is_negative = is_negative


@sp.add_test(name = "Test")
def test():
    scenario = sp.test_scenario()
    c = Test()
    scenario += c

    # Test with a positive integer
    scenario += c.check_negative(sp.pack(42))
    scenario.verify(c.data.is_negative == False)

    # Test with a negative integer
    scenario += c.check_negative(sp.pack(-42))
    scenario.verify(c.data.is_negative == True)
```